# You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one

Tags: php, paypal

I have made a paypal form to upload my custom shopping cart to paypal so customers can pay using payapal, however everytime I try to use it I am getting the following error on the paypal website:

"You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one."

Here is my code:

```
    <form id = "paypal_checkout" action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post">
        <input name = "cmd" value = "_cart" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "upload" value = "1" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "no_note" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "bn" value = "PP-BuyNowBF" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "tax" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "rm" value = "2" type = "hidden">

        <input name = "business" value = "my@mail.com" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "invoice" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "handling_cart" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "currency_code" value = "AUD" type = "hidden">
        <!--<input name = "lc" value = "EN" type = "hidden">-->
        <input name = "return" value = "http://www.#.com/page1.php?success=1&order=<?php echo $order_id; ?>" type = "hidden"> <!-- Change the domain as you wish -->
        <input name = "cbt" value = "Return to My Site" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "cancel_return" value = "http://www.#.com/page1.php?cancel=1" type = "hidden"> <!-- Change the domain as you wish -->
        <input name = "custom" value = "" type = "hidden">

        <div id = "item_1" class = "itemwrap">
            <input name = "item_name_1" value = "Rooms" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "quantity_1" value = "<?php echo $rooms; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "amount_1" value = "<?php echo $rooms_price; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "shipping_1" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        </div>

        <div id = "item_2" class = "itemwrap">
            <input name = "item_name_2" value = "Bath" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "quantity_2" value = "<?php echo $bath; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "amount_2" value = "<?php echo $bath_price; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "shipping_2" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        </div>

        <div id = "item_3" class = "itemwrap">
            <input name = "item_name_3" value = "Home" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "quantity_3" value = "<?php echo $home; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "amount_3" value = "<?php echo $home_price; ?>" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "shipping_3" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        </div>

        <input id = "ppcheckoutbtn" value = "Checkout" class = "button" type = "submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Well, it seems you are not passing an int in your quantity field. Check if it's not a string or float. Try to cast it with `(int) $value`

Comment: i try it… but same result.. :(

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear. Look at (and share with StackOverflow, if you want help) the generated form (page/html) with the actual quantity values in it. Presumably the PHP is not doing what you expect in some circumstange, and one of the quantities is not a positive integer or the generated form has some other validity issue (e.g. is an element not getting closed properly somewhere? Does the debug menu in your browser show any html issues on the page?)

Comment: no html issues… i check it… :( This is full page : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YeuB3rJ-_1ClnLeiwgAuUy5otW91Y22U5B4eHQeUMw8/edit

Comment: Seeing the code with dynamic PHP values doesn't help.  Need to see the HTML as it is after everything is rendered.